# Java class with possibly-missing run-time dependencies

Tags: java, classloader, dependency-management

I have utility class U that depends on a library X, and must go in a package that will be used from programs with X available (where it should do its normal stuff), and places without X (where it should do nothing). Without splitting the class in two, I have found a simple pattern that solves this:

```
package foo;
import bar.MisteriousX;

public class U {
    static private boolean isXPresent = false;
    static {
        try {
            isXPresent = (null != U.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("bar.MisteriousX"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // loading of a sample X class failed: no X for you
        }
    }
    public static void doSomething() {
        if (isXPresent) {
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() { 
                    System.err.println("X says " + MisteriousX.say());
                }
            }.run();
        } else {
            System.err.println("X is not there");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) { doSomething(); } 
}
```

With this pattern, U requires X present to compile, but works as expected when run with or without X present. Unless all accesses to the X library are inside internal classes, this code launches a classloader exception.

Questions: is import resolution guaranteed to work like this everywhere, or will it depend on JVM/ClassLoader implementation? Is there an established pattern for this? Is the above code-snippet too hackish to make it into production?

Comment: This is why you have frameworks like spring for dependency injection. Either way, I think you should be using an interface here which will always be available instead of checking for the existence of a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, when a class is first loaded, then if it refers to a class which does not exist, that might lead to an error. So yes, having one class do the check and another class actually access the external package without reflection will work as intended, at least on all implementations I've seen so far. It doesn't have to be an *inner* class.

The [Linking section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4) in the JVM specs give great freedom to implementations. If you don't use the two-class approach, then the *verification* of `U` in an implementation using eager linking will cause an attempt to *load* `X` which results in a `LinkageError`. The specs don't require the references class to be verified as well, but neither does it forbid such early verification. It does however require that

> any error detected during resolution must be thrown at a point in the
>   program that (directly or indirectly) uses a symbolic reference to the
>   class or interface.

Seems you should be safe to assume that the error is only thrown when you actually access your inner class. If you look at the history of this answer, you will find that I already changed my opinion twice, so there will be no guarantees that I read it correctly this time… :-/

Answer (score 3):

I do a similar thing in [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), in order to load optional logging framework dependencies. I share your feelings about the fact that this is a bit of a hack, though. A sample code snippet of field initialisation, depending on class availability:

```
public final class JooqLogger {

    private org.slf4j.Logger slf4j;
    private org.apache.log4j.Logger log4j;
    private java.util.logging.Logger util;

    public static JooqLogger getLogger(Class<?> clazz) {
        JooqLogger result = new JooqLogger();

        // Prioritise slf4j
        try {
            result.slf4j = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz);
        }

        // If that's not on the classpath, try log4j instead
        catch (Throwable e1) {
            try {
                result.log4j = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(clazz);
            }

            // If that's not on the classpath either, ignore most of logging
            catch (Throwable e2) {
                result.util= java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(clazz.getName());
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    [...]
```

And then, later on, the logger switch, depending on previously loaded classes:

```
public boolean isTraceEnabled() {
    if (slf4j != null) {
        return slf4j.isTraceEnabled();
    }
    else if (log4j != null) {
        return log4j.isTraceEnabled();
    }
    else {
        return util.isLoggable(Level.FINER);
    }
}
```

The rest of the source code can be seen [here](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/tools/JooqLogger.java). In essence, I have a compile-time dependency to both slf4j, and log4j, which I render optional at runtime using a similar pattern as you.

This could cause problems in OSGi environments, for instance, where classloading is a bit more complex than when you just use the standard JDK / JRE classloading mechanisms. However, so far I wasn't made aware of any issues

Comment: The actual 'U' is inspired in my own log-configuration utility class... I may end up using your implementation.

Comment: Feel free to use it. It works pretty well, also in productive environments. But so far, I couldn't prove whether it is formally correct, so your question is very interesting...

Comment: Lukas, although it may be fine in the context of this question, the "optional logging framework pattern" is evil. See http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#optional_dependency

Comment: @Ceki: Thanks for that hint. As the OP's question really is about logging, maybe you could give an answer to this question? Note, I don't agree with the text of your link. I don't have those problems. My wrapper only delegates to the real logger. It has no features of its own. For instance, it only depends on `org.slf4j.Logger`, which is said to be backwards compatible. Besides, it fetches a logger from `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` using the call-site class, which is also OK

Comment: @Lukas The code you provided is fine for the purposes of this question. As for your wrapper, while it does not suffer from coupling to SLF4J, it clobbers caller location information. It supports only one parameter. It merges the log message and its parameters. Most importantly, you are forcing your users to learn about how jOOQ does logging. By the way, I like your coding style.

Comment: @Ceki: You're right, the caller information is not very accurate. I guess there's no good solution to that problem, short of instrumentation, which I think would be overkill

Comment: @Lukas: SLF4J supports caller location information for log4j, jul and logback. If didn't I wouldn't have mentioned it as a critique of your wrapper.